# Working on ATM project and can't seem to get it to read and write to a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently working on a small ATM project that records how much money is located in a total of 3 accounts using an array.  Everything is working smoothly however I can't seem to get it to read and write to a file.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```js
package atmfun;

import atmfun.ATMAccounts;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Account implements java.io.Serializable 
{

    double startingBalance = 100;
    int firstdate = 0;
    int seconddate = 0;
    int datediff = 0;
    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    boolean dateflag = false;
    double rate = 0;
    double ratetime = 0;
    ATMAccounts[] ATMAccount = new ATMAccounts[3];
    int i = 0;
    private String path;
  //  cal1 = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.ATMAccount[0] = new ATMAccounts();
        acc.ATMAccount[1] = new ATMAccounts();
        acc.ATMAccount[2] = new ATMAccounts();

            do
            {
            System.out.println("Which account? 1, 2 or 3?");        
            System.out.println("Enter 4 to exit.");
            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            acc.i = sc.nextInt();
            if (acc.i == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                System.exit(1);
            } else 
            {
                acc.i--;
                acc.menu();
            }         
            } while(acc.i != 4); 
    }


    public void menu() throws IOException
    {
        int input = 0;
        do{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 for deposit, 2 for withdraw, 3 for check balance, 4 exit");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        try
        {
            input = sc.nextInt();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("You made a mistake, try again");
        }

            writeFile();    //IT BREAKS RIGHT HERE
            readFile();

        if (input == 1)
        {
            deposit();
            writeFile();
            readFile();
        }
        if(input == 2)
        {
            withdraw();
        }
        if(input == 3)
        {
            checkBalance();
        }
        if (input == 4);
        {
            System.out.println("Return to account menu.");

        }

        }while (input != 4);
    }

    public void deposit() throws IOException
    {    
      getDate1();
      //getInterest();
      System.out.print("Deposit Amount: ");
      Scanner AC = new Scanner(System.in);
      double dep = AC.nextDouble();
      ATMAccount[i].balance = ATMAccount[i].balance + dep;
      NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
      System.out.println("New Balance: " + nf.format(ATMAccount[i].balance + ratetime));

    }

    public void withdraw()
    {
      System.out.print("Withdraw: ");
      Scanner WD = new Scanner(System.in);
      double with = WD.nextDouble();
      ATMAccount[i].balance = ATMAccount[i].balance - with;
      NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
      System.out.print("New Balance: " + nf.format(ATMAccount[i].balance));
      System.out.println("");

    }

    public void checkBalance() throws IOException
    {
     getDate2();
     getInterest();
     NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
     System.out.print("Amount: " + nf.format(ATMAccount[i].balance + ratetime));
     System.out.println("");


    }

    public void getInterest()
    {
        int datediff = seconddate - firstdate;
        rate = .05/365;
        double ratetime = Math.pow(1+rate,datediff); //        datediff*(1+rate);
        ATMAccount[i].balance = ATMAccount[i].balance * ratetime;
        firstdate = seconddate;
    }

    public void getDate1() throws IOException 
    {

        System.out.print("Enter todays date(mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputText = br.readLine();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
      //Date date= new Date();
        Date date = formatter.parse(inputText, pos);

        cal1.setTime(date);

        firstdate = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        dateflag = true;
    }

    public void getDate2() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.print("Enter todays date(mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputText = br.readLine();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date date = formatter.parse(inputText, pos);

        cal2.setTime(date);
        seconddate = cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        dateflag = true;
    }

//    public void readFile()
//    {
//        try
//        {
//            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accountINFO.txt"));
//            
//        } catch (IOException e)
//                {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//    }

//    public void writeFile()
//    {
//        try
//        {   
//            File file = new File ("./cheekymonkey/file.out");
//           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./cheekymonkey/file.out");
//           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
//           oos.writeObject(i);
//              oos.flush();
//              fos.close();
//                   
//                    
//            
//            
//          
//        } catch (IOException e)
//                {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//        
//        
//    }

    public void writeFile ()
    {


        {
        try {
                                    File file = new File("accountINFO.txt");

                                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                                    if (!file.exists()) {
                                            file.createNewFile();
                                    }

                                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                                    //Or comment out above line and create for loop to loop through
                                    //and write all accounts out.
                                    String tempString = ATMAccount[i].getAcctNum();
                                    double tempNumber = ATMAccount[i].getBalance();
                                    String tempStringNum = Double.toString(tempNumber);
                                    bw.write("|");
                                    bw.write(tempStringNum);
                                    bw.newLine();
                                    bw.close();

                                    System.out.println("Done");

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    }

    }

    public void readFile() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr); 

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accountINFO.txt"));
            int counter = 0;

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sCurrentLine, "|");

                                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                                {
                                    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                                    {

                                        if(i == 0)
                                        {
                                            String tempAcct = st.nextToken();
                                            ATMAccount[counter].setAcctNum(tempAcct);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ATMAccount[counter].setBalance(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                counter++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e)
                {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try debugging your program? What is the exception it is throwing?

Comment: Yeah I tried debugging, but it didn't really get me anywhere.  Whenever it hits the writeFile() and readFile() I have up top it gives me a huge nullpointerexception error.

Comment: Follow the stacktrace & put a debugger where the null is occurring. You will get to know which variable is null. Put a debugger in your writeFile() method

Comment: Check the Double.toString(tempNumber) line. Seems you forget to give an initial balance.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException occurs if you haven't initialize your objects. There are eight primitive types which does not need to initialize, which has a default value.
byte         0,
short        0,
int            0,
long         0L,
float         0.0f,
double     0.0d,
char          '\u0000',
boolean false.